# How to use SPARQLExecute for SPARQLSelect on Entities?

Tags: memory, entity, sql

When using [`SPARQLSelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphStore/ref/SPARQLSelect.html) on [Entity Types](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EntityTypes.html) the entire entity store is downloaded to the local cache.

For example,

```
SPARQLSelect[
  {
     RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["city"], EntityProperty["City", "Name"],
       SPARQLVariable["cityName"]]
     } /; 
    SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["cityName"], 
     "Lon"] -> 
   {"city"}
  ][Entity["City"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This first downloads 164,599 entity values to the local cache before evaluating the query locally.

With [`SPARQLExecute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphStore/ref/SPARQLExecute.html) the query can be evaluated on the graph database server and only the results returned.  However I have not been able to find the Wolfram graph-store entity URL in the documentation.

Is there a way to `SPARQLExecute` an entity query on the Wolfram graph-store URL? Or, alternatively, execute the SPARQL query without it killing the kernel?

I would like to evaluate the following but, after the entity stores are downloaded, the kernel dies just after a system low memory warning pop-up appears.

```
SPARQLSelect[
  {
     RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["city"], EntityProperty["City", "Name"],
       SPARQLVariable["cityName"]],
     RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["airport"], 
      EntityProperty["Airport", "Name"], SPARQLVariable["airportName"]]
     } /; 
    SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["airportName"], 
     SPARQLVariable["cityName"]] -> 
   {"city", "airport"}
  ][{Entity["City"], Entity["Airport"]}]
```

Comment: I am not aware of a publicly available SPARQL endpoint for the Wolfram Knowledgebase (with which you could use `SPARQLService` or similar). It might be worth asking about this on the Wolfram Community forum.

Comment: Cross-posted on Wolfram Community [1674179](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1674179).

Comment: Confirmed on Wolfram Community forums that the kernel crash part of this question is an implementation issue with the SPARQL functions in version 12.0.